# How to reference a file in Payara

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara

Simply put I need to read a schema.json file for `org.everit.json.schema`. In Eclipse I naively for testing I did it like this:

```
new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("./src/main/resources/schemas/Schema.json"))));
```

However when compiling and deploying to Payara I am getting a java exception file not found.

Where is or what is the best way to reference a file on the server in code (cannot seem to find a documented approach for this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path where Schema.json is located indicates a Maven project hierarchy. As such, the `src/main/resources` folder is in the classpath. The best way to get the contents of this file from a non-static method is:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/schemas/Schema.json");
```

And read the `InputStream`.

2 notes:

- Exception and resource handling not shown
- From a static method you need to use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: Correct it is maven and this does the trick. Error handling is 100% done just kind of bloated for this post.